# Gerar próxima sequência de um "indice"

Tags: jquery

Estou com um problema em gerar uma sequência para um "indice".

Como exemplo, se eu pegar o número 1.2 , queria gerar como sequência o número 1.2.4 ou se eu pegar o 1.2.2 queria gerar o 1.2.2.1

```
<select>
  <option>1.1       </option>
  <option>1.1.1     </option>
  <option>1.1.2     </option>
  <option>1.2       </option>
  <option>1.2.1     </option>
  <option>1.2.2     </option>
  <option>1.2.3     </option>
  <option>1.2.3.1   </option>
  <option>1.3       </option>
  <option>1.3.1     </option>
</select>
```

no caso eu teria que verificar quantos elementos esse "indice" teria e gerar um novo, mas estou com problema com a lógica dele.

Se alguém puder ajudar. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Qual é o padrão de geração desses números? Existe um valor máximo para cada sub-versão?

Comment: Tem que ser dentro de um `<select>`?? Se poder ser um lista comum tipo `ul li` fica bem fácil de resolver...

Comment: O que quer dizer com "gerar"? Vc quer criar um novo `option` com a sequência?

Comment: No caso, eu só queria gerar a próxima seguencia, não importa se é num input, span ou outra tags, e não tem limite na geração ou um valor máximo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma. As explicações estão comentadas no código:

```js
$("select").change(function(){
   
   var opts = $("option", this); // pego todos os options
   var opt  = $(":selected", this); // pego o option selecionado
   var idx  = opt.index(); // pego o índice do option selecionado
   var txt  = opt.text().trim(); // pego o texto do option e elimino os espaços nas bordas
   var m; // flag para testar regex

   // aqui verifico se existe uma subsequência com .1
   for(var x=idx+1; x<opts.length; x++){
      var re = new RegExp("^"+txt+".1");
      m = re.test($(opts[x]).text().trim());
      if(m) break;
   }

   if(m){ // se existe, varro o resto do select para definir a próxima sequência
      var y = 2; // começo com 2, já que o 1 já existe
      for(var x=idx+2; x<opts.length; x++){
         var txt2 = $(opts[x]).text().trim();
         var re = new RegExp("^"+txt+"."+y);
         m = re.test(txt2);
         if(!m) break;
         y++;
      }
      var seq = txt+"."+y;
   }else{ // se não existe, crio a subsequência com .1
      var seq = txt+".1";
   }
   
   console.log(seq);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1.1       </option>
  <option>1.1.1     </option>
  <option>1.1.2     </option>
  <option>1.2       </option>
  <option>1.2.1     </option>
  <option>1.2.2     </option>
  <option>1.2.3     </option>
  <option>1.2.3.1   </option>
  <option>1.3       </option>
  <option>1.3.1     </option>
  <option>1.3.2     </option>
  <option>1.3.3     </option>
  <option>1.3.4     </option>
  <option>1.3.5     </option>
  <option>1.3.6     </option>
  <option>1.3.7     </option>
  <option>3         </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas eu encontrei um problema, digamos que eu tenha um índice 1.3.1 que vai até 1.3.7, e depois eu adicionar um índice 3, e pedir pra gerar um sequência do mesmo, ele vai gerar um índice de 3.8 e não um 3.1

Comment: sim, no caso vc precisaria dos options de 1.3.1 a 1.3.7 para acontecer o erro, pois ele não está comparando índice todo, ele pegou só o 3.1 ao 3.7 do índice 1, e gerou a sequência 3.8 quando pedi pra ele gerar a sequência do índice 3

Comment: não resolveu o problema, se eu seleciono um índice com um caracter somente, ele somente adiciona o .1 ao final, se eu já tivesse o 3.1 ele continuou gerando o 3.1 como sequência. E se

Comment: E continua com o erro, eu tinha um índice 1.1.1.2.3 e tentei gerar um índice 1.1.2,  tendo os índice 1.1.2.1 e 1.1.2.2 mas ele gerou um índice 1.1.2.4

Comment: Ok! Vou revisar todo o código.

Comment: Pronto. Dá uma olhada agora.